# Organize and pass resources between Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm new to android dev, and I have a question about resources.

I'd like to have 2 activies: 1 with buttons, that will lead to a 2nd activity.

The 2nd activity will have some fixed text, and some variable text, depending on which button has been pressed on Activity 1.

I figured that I could pass a resource in the intent.

So my idea, was to create 1 xml file for each button, with all the info needed in Activity 2 to update the text accordingly.

Now I want to organize my resources so it's easier to manage (especially when the application will get bigger).

I'd like to be able to organize my resources as such:

```
res
  drawable
  font
  layout
  mipmap
  values
    heroes
      hero1.xml
      hero2.xml
      hero3.xml
```

and be able to call my intent as such:

```
intent.putExtra("heroData", R.values.heroes.hero1)
```

if I click on the button for 'Hero 1' in the main activity.
Then, from activity 2, I'll be able to get the information about hero1 (hp, armor, etc...)

Unfortunately, it seems Android is picky about how 'R' is built, and you can't just add directories that will be accessible through R.values.xxxx

Is it the wrong approach to do this, or did I just missed something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please refresh resources understanding based on this compact article:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

In short, you must not go with values/xyz/abc.xml pattern. If really really needed, you could go with values/abc1.xml, values/abc2.xml (not necessarily values/strings.xml).

Also, this will not work `intent.putExtra("heroData", R.values.heroes.hero1)`. You can access any resource anywhere inside the app assuming context is available. No need to try and pass file of resources somewhere.

PS: "The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming" (https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Comment: Thanks. I've read this article, but I want to keep things organized. If I start to put everything in the 'values' directory, it will quickly become a mess. Now I just used heroes, as examples, but later I will add weapons, items, etc... If I have everything in the same directory, I will have hundreds of files in it, this will not be manageable.

Comment: My present strings.xml has ~2.5k lines. They are divided into sections by human readable comments and there is resources naming involved (prefixes etc). Why can't you go that path? Will you have more then I currently have?

Comment: I don't know, maybe my brain has been modified by too much OOP, but I'd like to have 1 file per item. Another problem with having everything in the same file is that when you have multiple people working on it, it can quickly become a mess (with the push and commits). If you have separated files, it's easier for people to work on different files.

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately cannot create subdirectories within values. You can as mentioned created explicit resource files and that can serve as your file organization (res/values/heroes1.xml, res/values/weapons1.xml, etc).

Comment: So, how could I organize my data ? Is there some alternative ? Thanks